# Python Paraview

Tags: python, paraview

How to extract data from server to the client in Paraview parallel running mode

my script is:
def getNumberOfBlocks(px):
    data1 = servermanager.Fetch(px,0)

```
data2 = servermanager.Fetch(px,1)
group = vtk.vtkMultiBlockDataGroupFilter()
group.AddInputConnection(group.GetOutputPortn())
group.AddInputConnection(group.GetOutputPort())
group.Update()
group.AddInputConnection(transformer2.GetOutputPort())
data3 = group.GetOutputPort()

data = vtk.vtkMultiBlockDataGroupFilter.SafeDownCast(data3)
return data.GetNumberOfBlocks()
```

px is a proxy from where i am getting data.
there are two port , i need to fetch the data from these port all at a time.

thanks for help.

Comment: This is a bit offtopic, but from python you might be interested in [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/). Is a higher level package built on top of VTK. Way easier to use with same achievable results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your script - won't it always return 3?

If you just want to get the number of blocks and px is of type `vtkSMSourceProxy`, you can use the following:

```
def getNumberOfBlocks(px):
  di = GetDataInformation()
  cdi = di.GetCompositeDataInformation()
  return cdi.GetNumberOfChildren()
```